# Android Studio Flamingo eating up all memory when opening a project

Tags: android-studio, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

After updating to Flamingo, I'm facing a weird problem where Android Studio eats up all available memory when I open a project. Android Studio starts many gradle Daemons in start and they start to eat up memory until it gets exhausted. It mostly happens with old apps and I suspect it might be related to gradle versions. Has anybody faced a similar problem? Is there any solution for it?

You can see a part of the list of all running gradle daemons:
[image]